# Android: How to read low level network info (RSCP, EcN0, Layer 3 Signalling)?

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, umts

I'm trying to create android app for measuring 2G 3G network similar to [QualiPoc](http://www.swissqual.com/index.php/systems/qualipoc_android.html).

I'm aware that there is basic Android API for gathering Network Info, for example: [How to know Location Area Code and Cell ID in android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152373/how-to-know-location-area-code-and-cell-id-in-android-phone)

However, this API is rather limited, and not sufficient (for example: on my phone RSCP values are refreshed every 10 seconds...)

Since my phone is rooted, I've managed to run basic AT commands on the qualcomm modem /dev/smd0 
[How to send a command to android and then get its answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306813/how-to-send-a-command-to-android-and-then-get-its-answer)

What AT Commands should I use to read RxLevel, RXQuality, CellID, LocationAreaCode, RSCP, EcN0, CQI?

Is it possible to read Level 3 signalization by using AT Commands?

Is there better Android Qualcomm API to get these informations?

What is Gobi / QMI interface and can it be used for reading Network data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What AT Commands should I use to read RxLevel, RXQuality, CellID, LocationAreaCode, RSCP, EcN0, CQI?

AT+CREG? gives CellId and LAC

+CSQ gives RSSI in dBm and RXQUAL

See 3GPP TS 27.007 for standard 3GPP AT commands, available from [www.3gpp.org](http://3gpp.org).
Your device probably supports some manufacturer-specific AT commands as well.

> Is it possible to read Level 3 signalization by using AT Commands?

No, you can't read RRC messages, only selected parameters from them.
You can read the layer 3 signalling messages using Qualcomm diagnostic tools, but you have to have an agreement with Qualcomm to get these.

> Is there better Android Qualcomm API to get these informations?
> What is Gobi / QMI interface and can it be used for reading Network data?

Gobi/QMI is the Qualcomm interface.  There is also information about AT commands supported by Qualcomm devices at
[Qualcomm documentation](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download)

Comment: Can I read bsic, bcch gsm values with qualcomm apis? I am browsing their portal but not sure is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window you can run an e.g., (busybox) awk script that processes the output of logcat -b radio, producing e.g.,

```
16:33:18 CREG: 1, "28D6", "01C6B623", 2
[10454 29799971 00454 46627]
16:33:19 ECSQ: 8, 99, -392, [-98] -455, -62
```

Anyway, "logcat -b radio" might already contain all that you are looking for.

Answer (score -5):

There is application in Android market called " RF Signal Tracker" this will give you RF levels along with Cell ID info.

Comment: An app recommendation doesn't really answer the programming question.