# How can I get response of certain at command which I entered in android mobile phone?

Tags: android, shell, terminal, runtime.exec

I'm trying to get low level info. from the modem of my mobile phone.
So I tried to enter AT Commands, but I couldn't get the response.

I tried the first answer in this link:
[How to send a command to android and then get its answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306813/how-to-send-a-command-to-android-and-then-get-its-answer)

The problem is: There is a loop which dose not stop     while (mBlinker != null){...}

pleas help me correcting this code or suggest another one.
thank u :)